# How to go from .dot to graph using an api

Tags: graph, png, graphviz, dot

Is there a way to go from .dot to graph (png) through an API?. I can neither install a sw locally nor using a web browser. Therefore is there a web url to which I can send the http request containing the body of the below graphviz data? perhaps a POST or a GET request using postman or soapUI, so that the response of such request should contain the png representing the graph?. The following is a simple example.

```
digraph G {
"A"->"B";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
"B"->"C";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
"C"->"D";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
"D"->"E";  
}
```

I will be having more .dot request with more complex combinations. Please let me know if there is such url, or an advice on how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried viz-js.com?  You can build it yourself from [github](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js).  With the source code at hand, I'm sure you could achieve what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm Image-Charts founder.

Pass your dot file content to the webservice and you will get an SVG image, like so:

```
https://image-charts.com/chart
?cht=gv:dot
&chl=digraph G { "A"->"B"; "B"->"C"; "C"->"D"; "D"->"E"; }
```

Outputs:

[image]